# Visual Studio 2008 Professional with MSDN Professional to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio

With Visual Studio 2010 right around the corner, what does Visual Studio 2008 Professional with MSDN Professional upgrade to in Visual Studio 2010? Do I get 2010 for free, if I buy this flavor of 2008 now?

Comment: To the closers: this is on-topic for SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your subscription is still active when Visual Studio 2010 is released, then yes, you will be able to download Visual Studio 2010.

Microsoft has changed the MSDN licensing a bit; the "Visual Studio 2008 Professional with MSDN Professional" will just be called "Visual Studio 2010 Professional with MSDN."

There's a [press release from Microsoft explaining the changes](http://www.microsoft.com/presspass/newsroom/developer/factsheets/VS2010PackagingFS.docx) (MS Word Link).

Comment: I've only seen getting Visual Studio 2008 with MSDN Premium getting the Visual Studio 2010 with MSDN.

Comment: Visual Studio works just like any of the other products available through MSDN:  when new versions come out, if you have an active subscription, you can download and use them.  The color blocks in the picture on that press release show the correspondence between the old subscription tiers and the new ones (the prices are about the same as well, IIRC).

Answer (score 0):

If your MSDN subscription is active on April 12th, you'll end up receiving Visual Studio 2010 Premium with MSDN Professional through the "[Ultimate Offer](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/offers)" that is available.

I have some more information about the editions available in a [blog post that I wrote](http://www.edsquared.com/2010/04/02/Which+Edition+Of+Visual+Studio+2010+Do+I+Buy.aspx).